# How to read all element under a custom section from web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I want to filter some browser by useragent and regex,so put the filtering rule in web.config seems a good solution.
But I can not figure how to read the all element under a custom section from web.config.

This is my config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <add name="ViewFilterModule" type="ViewFilterModule"/>
    </modules>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="ViewFilterGroup">
          <section 
            name="ViewFilter" 
            type="CMG.ViewFilter" 
            allowLocation="true" 
            allowDefinition="Everywhere"
          />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <ViewFilterGroup>
        <ViewFilter name="ucweb" regex="ucweb" redirect="~/ucweb.html" />
        <ViewFilter name="operamini" regex="opera mini" redirect="~/operamini.html" />
        <ViewFilter name="ucweb" regex="ucweb" redirect="~/ucweb.html" />
        <ViewFilter name="operamini" regex="opera mini" redirect="~/operamini.html" />
        <ViewFilter name="ucweb" regex="ucweb" redirect="~/ucweb.html" />
        <ViewFilter name="operamini" regex="opera mini" redirect="~/operamini.html" />
    </ViewFilterGroup>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and this is my code :

```
public class ViewFilterSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("name", DefaultValue = "", IsRequired = true)]
    [StringValidator(InvalidCharacters = "~!@#$%^&*()[]{}/;'\"|\\", MinLength = 1, MaxLength = 20)]
    public String Name
    {
        get
        {
            return (String)this["name"];
        }
        set
        {
            this["name"] = value;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("regex", DefaultValue = "", IsRequired = false)]
    public String Regex
    {
        get
        { return (String)this["regex"]; }
        set
        { this["regex"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("redirect", DefaultValue = "", IsRequired = false)]
    public String Redirect
    {
        get
        { return (String)this["redirect"]; }
        set
        { this["redirect"] = value; }
    }
}
```

I just want to read all `ViewFilter` elements under `ViewFilterGroup` in my custom moudle.

Comment: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/032807-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Few things you have missing.

Firstly, we'll need a class that corresponds to your `ViewFilter` and we're going to move all of your properties into there, something like:

```
public class ViewFilterElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("name", DefaultValue = "", IsRequired = true)]
    [StringValidator(InvalidCharacters = "~!@#$%^&*()[]{}/;'\"|\\", MinLength = 1, MaxLength = 20)]
    public String Name
    {
        get { return (String)this["name"]; } set { this["name"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("regex", DefaultValue = "", IsRequired = false)]
    public String Regex
    {
        get { return (String)this["regex"]; } set { this["regex"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("redirect", DefaultValue = "", IsRequired = false)]
    public String Redirect
    {
        get { return (String)this["redirect"]; } set { this["redirect"] = value; }
    }
}
```

Then have a `ConfigurationElementCollection` property that corresponds to your `ViewFilterGroup`:

```
public class ViewFilterCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new ViewFilterElement();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((ViewFilterElement)element).Name;
    }
}
```

Then in your `ViewFilterSection` class, you can have a property that returns a list on your new `ViewFilterElement` type, like so

```
public class ViewFilterSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("", IsRequired = true, IsDefaultCollection = true)]
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(ViewFilterCollection), AddItemName = "ViewFilter")]
    private ViewFilterCollection ViewFilterCollection
    {
        get { return (ViewFilterCollection)this[string.Empty]; }
        set { this[string.Empty] = value; }
    }

    public static List<ViewFilterElement> ViewFilters
    {
        get
        {
            ViewFilterSection sec = (ViewFilterSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("ViewFilterGroup");

            return sec.ViewFilterCollection.As<ViewFilterElement>().ToList();
        }
    }
}
```